# How to integrate ink file picker in asp.net web site?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing asp.net application.
When user click on "upload id card photo" button ink file picker page should come.
And after clicking on done in ink file picker user should redirect to previous page with image in image control.

Comment: I have account on ink picker but I am not getting how to add logic for it

Answer (score 0):

Just This

```
 <input type="file" id="Photo" />
```

To get upload the upload file path and if u need to get this image as separate page use dialog box or fancy box and get file upload path the save it in your jquery variable or hidden control to one variable for example

```
$('#photo').change(function () {
  var = $('#photo').val();
});
```

refer dialog box to this link  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: can we use direct ink file picker?

Comment: For that u need to pay see this link https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.inkfilepicker.plugin.confluence.filepicker

Comment: will it redirect to ink file picker page?

Comment: On button click event user should navigate to upload file page in ink picker

Comment: for that you need to use ajax for holding the data using static variable in server side

Comment: kk. but this link will properly n for uploading files?